# Interating through embedded data with Jade and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have a data structure that has embedded data in mongodb like this.

```
{
    "Parent Name": "John",
    "Children": {
        "Child": {
            "Name": "Joe",
            "Age": "10"
        },
        "Child": {
            "Name": "Mary",
            "Age": "6"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a Jade template to display the data which works fine for the parent's name but I can't figure out how to get the children data to display.  The code below displays [object Object] for the Children which I figured would happen.

```
each parent, i in parents
    tr
        td #{parent.ParentName}
        td #{parent.Children}
```

I'm trying to get the Children's name and age to display.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple here but I'm new to Jade, Express, and Mongodb so I haven't been able to figure it out or find a post that explains it.  I've tried...

```
each child, c in parent.Children

parent.Children[0].Name
```

but they don't seem to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your object above, `Children` is not an array, it is an object.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my comment, I think the source of your problem is that your object does not contain an array for Children, it contains another object, and a bad one at that as it had duplicate property names.

I think if you start with the correct object, you are on the right track with your jade code

```
{
    "ParentName": "John",
    "Children": [
        {
            "Name": "Joe",
            "Age": "10"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Mary",
            "Age": "6"
        }       
    ]
}
```

You asked why the object was 'bad' in your comment, it's because this (which I cleaned up since there were some trailing commas after the "age" property):

```
var myobj = {
    "ParentName": "John",
    "Children": {
        "Child": {
            "Name": "Joe",
            "Age": "10"
        },
        "Child": {
            "Name": "Mary",
            "Age": "6"
        }
    }
};

console.log(require('util').inspect(myobj));
```

produces this:

```
{ ParentName: 'John',
  Children: { Child: { Name: 'Mary', Age: '6' } } }
```

Because you have a duplicate property name. How are you getting the object you described above from Mongo?

Comment: I'm pulling the data out of mongodb as it was stored from a different system so I don't have a lot of control over that.  The repeated fields are needed because its representing relational data.  Each parent can have multiple children so I'm not sure what is "bad" about that.  Each child needs the same property name unless I'm missing something obvious here.  Maybe it needs to be reformatted before it gets sent to Jade?

Comment: I removed the trailing commas in my post.  That's what I get for hand typing the example.  I'm just doing db.collection('mydata').find() to get the data from mongodb.

Comment: Maybe someone else wants to take a swing at this. Unless something rather unusual is happening, Mongo would be returning an array, not an object with duplicate properties, and if so, you should probably report this as a bug to the Mongo folks (but I find this unlikely). Maybe paste a console log directly of the object as received from Monogo such as I illustrated in my updated answer.